# JS - Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment

Tags: javascript

The piece of code below seems to work in online code editors but when using on Cloud9 IDE, it comes up with that error message. Is there a way to sort this or alternatively write this bit of code?

The error appears on line 3, the for loop statement.

```
var text1 = document.querySelector('input[name="contract-type"]').value;
var select1 = document.getElementById('contract-type-list');
for(var i, j=0; i = select1.options[j]; j++){
    if(i.text == text1){
        select1.selectedIndex = j;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @pilchard But it looks like they want to assign it, since that's the way they update `i` in each iteration.

Comment: When you click on the warning message there's probably an option to ignore it for this line. Use that since you're writing it this way intentionally.

Comment: In that case, `i = select1.options[j]` should probably be `j < select1.options.length`, and assign, and compare, `i` in the loop body itself.

Comment: Though I guess this implicitly tests truthiness of `select1.options[j]`

Answer (score 1):

The linter is warning you that `i = select1.options[j]` is a strange expression to be checking for truthyness, because it's an assignment. While you could ignore the rule, a better approach would be to iterate through the option children from `querySelectorAll` or `.children` or with the collection's iterator instead of going through `.options[index]`.

```
var text1 = document.querySelector('input[name="contract-type"]').value;
var select1 = document.getElementById('contract-type-list');
for (const [i, option] of [...select1.options].entries()) {
    if (option.text == text1) {
        select1.selectedIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Or, if the value is definitely one of the options, just do

```
document.getElementById('contract-type-list').value = document.querySelector('input[name="contract-type"]').value;
```

or, if it might not exist:

```
const inputText = document.querySelector('input[name="contract-type"]').value;
const select = document.getElementById('contract-type-list');
const matchingOption = [...select.children].find(option => option.text === inputText);
if (matchingOption) {
    select.value = matchingOption.ariaValueMax;
}
```